# Improve postgreql insert performance when compared to Oracle. Low memory utilization by Postgresql threads

Tags: oracle, postgresql, insert

I am trying to improve the performance of Postgresql (version 9.2.3) inserts for a simple table with 1 bigint, 1 varchar, 1 float and 2 time stamps.

A simple replication of my JDBC program is attached. Here are the important points I want to mention:

1. I am running this program on the same system which hosts the PostgreSQL DB. (64 GB RAM and 8 CPUs.)
2. I am using INSERT statements AND I DO NOT want to use COPY statement. I have read and understand the COPY performs better but I am tuning the insert performance here.
3. I am using PreparedStatement.addbatch() and executeBatch() to insert in batches of 1000's

The performance of the insert scales well when I increase the batch size but flattens out at around a batch size of 8000. What I notice is that the postgresql thread on the system is CPU saturated as observed by the "top" command. The CPU usage of the postgres thread steadily increases and tops out at 95% when the batch size reaches 8K. The other interesting thing I notice is that it is using only up to 200MB of RAM per thread.

In comparison an Oracle DB scales much better and the the same number of insets with comparable batch sizes finish 3 to 4 times faster. I logged on to the Oracle DB machine (Sun Solaris machine) and noticed that the CPU utilization peaks out at a much bigger batch size and also each Oracle thread is using 6 to 8 GB of memory.

Given that I have memory to spare is there a way to increase the memory usage for a postgres thread for better performance?

Here are my current postgresql settings:

```
temp_buffers = 256MB                    

bgwriter_delay = 100ms
bgwriter_lru_maxpages = 1000
bgwriter_lru_multiplier = 4
maintenance_work_mem = 2GB              
shared_buffers = 8GB                    
vacuum_cost_limit = 800
work_mem = 2GB
max_connections = 100

checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
checkpoint_segments = 32
checkpoint_timeout =10min
checkpoint_warning =1min

wal_buffers = 32MB
wal_level = archive


cpu_tuple_cost = 0.03
effective_cache_size = 48GB
random_page_cost = 2

autovacuum = on
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 10ms
autovacuum_max_workers = 6
autovacuum_naptime = 5
autovacuum_vacuum_threshold = 100
autovacuum_analyze_threshold = 100
autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0.2
autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.1
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit = -1
```

Here are the measurements:

Time to insert 2 million rows in postgreql.
batch size - Execute batch time (sec)
1K - 73
2K - 64
4K - 60
8K - 59
10K - 59
20K - 59
40K - 59

Time to insert 4 million rows in Oracle.
batch size - Execute batch time (sec)
1K - 14
2K - 12
4K - 10
8K - 8.9
10K - 8.4

As you can see Oracle is inserting a 4 million row table much faster than Postgresql.

Here is the snippet of the program I am using for insertion.

```
stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE "
                + tableName
                + " (P_PARTKEY bigint not null, "
                + " P_NAME varchar(55) not null, "
                + " P_RETAILPRICE float not null, "
                + " P_TIMESTAMP Timestamp not null, "
                + " P_TS2 Timestamp not null)");

PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ? )");

        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            pstmt.setInt(1, i);
            pstmt.setString(2, "Magic Maker " + i);
            pstmt.setFloat(3, i);
            pstmt.setTimestamp(4, new Timestamp(1273017600000L));
            pstmt.setTimestamp(5, new Timestamp(1273017600000L));

            pstmt.addBatch();
            if (i % batchSize == 0) {
                pstmt.executeBatch();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Cross post: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108242/improve-postgreql-insert-performance-when-compared-to-oracle-low-memory-utiliza

Comment: Just a trivial suggestion: have you performed the same tests with another language? The differences between Oracle and PostgreSQL could be due at least in part to the differences in the JDBC drivers used.

Answer (score 0):

autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.002
autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor  = 0.001

You might need to change the above  parameters

Specifies a fraction of the table size to add to autovacuum_analyze_threshold when deciding whether to trigger an ANALYZE. The default is 0.1 (10% of table size). In our case we have lowered that to 0.002 to make it more aggressive.

Specifies a fraction of the table size to add to autovacuum_vacuum_threshold when deciding whether to trigger a VACUUM. The default is 0.2 (20% of table size).